# SpringBoot Configuration with application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I have a little SpringBoot Application, which can execute different functions via OpenLdap.

- `getUser`
- `createUser`
- `deleteUser`
- `etc.`

That works fine. Now i want to create an application.Yml, where i can manage different environments with different credentials. I read some tutorials, but i still have some understanding problems. Actually my code looks like that:

UserController:

```
...
protected static String serverURL = "xxxxx:90xx";
protected static String LdapBindDn = "cn=admin, xxxxx";
protected static String LdapPassword = "xxxx";
...

@RequestMapping(value = "/{userid:.+}",method = RequestMethod.GET,consumes="application/json",produces = "application/json")
public UserData getUser(@PathVariable String userid) {          
    DirContext context = connectToLdap();
    //some operations...
    context.close();    
    return user;
}
... // same for the other functions
```

My plan is now, that i want to specify the credentials in an extra application.yml instead of at the beginning of the UserController (see above).

Then i have created an application.yml in the src/main/resources:

```
# Actual environment
spring: 
  profiles.actives: development
---
# Dev Profile 
spring:
  profiles: dev  
datasource:
  serverUrl: ldaps://xxxxxx:90xx
  AdminName: xxxx
  AdminPassword: xxxxxx
  BaseDN: xxxxx
---
# Production Profile  
spring:
  profiles: prod     
datasource:
 serverUrl: ldaps://xxxx2:90xx
 AdminName: xxxxx2
 AdminPassword: xxxxx2
 BaseDN: xxxxxx
```

Now i need to call this configuration. I have read in one tutorial (http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2017/06/26/spring-boot-configuration-using-yaml) that i have to create an extra class "ApplicationProperties" for the properties of the .yml file.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource")
public class ApplicationProperties {

private String serverURL;
private String adminName;
private String adminPassword;
private String baseDN;

// Getter-/Setter-Methods
```

}

Now i need to define my variables from the beginning with the values from the .yml, right? I went back to my UserController and tried something like that:

```
private String serverURL;
private String adminName;
private String adminPassword;
private String baseDN;  

@Autowired   
ApplicationProperties appProp;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{userid:.+}",method = RequestMethod.GET,consumes="application/json",produces = "application/json")
public UserData getUser(@PathVariable String userid) {          
    DirContext context = connectToLdap();
    //some operations...
    context.close();    
    return user;
}
... // same for the other functions


private DirContext connectToLdap(){
    System.out.prinln(appProp.getServerURL());
    System.out.prinln(appProp.getAdminName());
    System.out.prinln(appProp.getAdminPassword());
    .... // Code for the Ldap connection 
}
```

But the variable "appProp" is still empty. I know, that here is somewhere a big understanding problem. I don't know how to call these properties from the .yml file.

Thanks for every help in advance!

Comment: [spring-boot config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) you can detailed info here like profile specific config, how to use in your class,etc

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I already read this. 
Can someone/you tell me, where my missunderstanding in the code is?

Comment: First, you can create profile based properties as spring boot picks them automatically, like `application-{profile}.{properties|yml}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get properties from your `.yml` file by creating a config class:

`application.yml`

```
datasource:
    serverUrl: ldaps://xxxxxx:90xx
    adminName: xxxx
    adminPassword: xxxxxx
    baseDN: xxxxx
```

`ApplicationConfig.java` class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private String serverUrl;
    private String adminName;
    private String adminPassword;
    private String baseDN;

    //getters setters

}
```

Then you can call your `ApplicationConfig` class

```
@Autowired
public ApplicationConfig app; 

public UserData getUser(@PathVariable String userid) {          
      DirContext context = connectToLdap();
      //some operations...
      appProp.getServerUrl();
      appProp.getAdminName();
      context.close();    
      return user;
}
```

And I recommend you to create profile based properties as spring boot picks them automatically, like `application-{profile}.{properties|yml}` 
You can create `application-production.yml` file and set your profile by adding `@Profile("production")` annotation in your class.

Comment: ok, i have updated the code like you said. See above. 
Now i get all the time a "java.lang.NullPointerException", because e.g. the function "appProp.getAdminName()" return "null".

Comment: Thank you very much "fiskra". Your version before was also working. The mistake was in the .yml File. 
I have written "profiles.actives: development", but it must be "profiles.active: development".
Now it's working! Thank youu.